# Distance between elements menu

Tags: html, css

I want to create a distance between menu items

This is the CSS code:

```
.menu-item a img
{
border:none;
box-shadow:none;
vertical-align:middle;
width:auto;
padding-left:20px;
}
```

This is the site

http://avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp

I managed to create a distance between elements but when put arrow hover over the menu ... the effect is elsewhere

What should I do to function properly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put your code in JSFiddle.net, url given is dead :)

Comment: sorry...now it`s OK :)

Comment: So you want spacing in between the li's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
#menu-meniu > li{padding-left: 20px}
```

or

```
#menu-meniu  li.menu-item-object-page{padding-left: 20px}
```

[image]

Comment: Only thing I would add is display: inline-block; But this should be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `padding` or `margin` for `ul li`, in example:

```
.menu li {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `!important`

Answer (score 0):

use margin in li .menu-item like

```
.menu-item {
    margin-right: 22px;
}
```